# Showing the existence of $\phi$ in the proof of the Implicit function Theorem

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

The Implicit Function Theorem I am working with:
Let $f \in C^1$ from an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $(y_0, x_0)$ be a point in this open set such that $f(y_0, x_0) = 0$, and
\begin{align*}
L =  \left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j} (y_0, x_0) \right)_{i,j = 1, \dots, m}
\end{align*}
is nonsingular. Then there exist open sets $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $(y_0, x_0) \in V \times U$, and to every $x \in U$, there exists a unique $y = \phi (x)$ in $V$ such that $f(\phi (x), x) = 0$, and $\phi \in C^1$ on $U$.

The proof begins by defining a function $F: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ as $F(y,x) = (f(y,x), x)$. Then the Inverse Function Theorem is applied to $F$. We have a neighborhoods $U' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ so that $F$ has a $C^1$ inverse on $W = F(V \times U')$, $U = \{x \in U': (0,x) \in W\}$

My question is: how can we show that there exists a $C^1$ function $\Phi: W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ so that $F^{-1}(y,x)) = (\Phi (y,x),x))$ on $W$? My approach has been to find the derivative of $F$ and then try to invert it by the Inverse Function Theorem, but I don't know how this shows $\Phi$ exists.

Furthermore, if we let $\phi(x) = \Phi(0,x)$, how can we show that $\phi$ then satisfies the conclusion of the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about all the open neighbourhoods. If you have an invertible mapping $F:\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n$ then we can consider the following two functions:
\begin{align}
\alpha:= \pi_{\Bbb{R}^m}\circ F^{-1}\quad \text{and}\quad \beta:=
\pi_{\Bbb{R}^n}\circ F^{-1},
\end{align}
where the $\pi$'s are the standard projections.
In other words, we can express $F^{-1}$ in the form $F^{-1}(u,v)=(\alpha(u,v),\beta(u,v))$. In your case $\Phi$ is $\alpha$ and $\beta=\pi_{\Bbb{R}^n}$ because of the additional assumption that $F(y,x)$ has the special form $(f(y,x),x)$.

Comment: Also for your last question, I'm not sure I can help you without you first explaining where you're stuck/what difficulties you're having in verifying the conclusion.

Comment: That $\phi$ has a continuous derivative.

Comment: @Andrew $F$ is $C^1$ so $F^{-1}$ is $C^1$ by the inverse function theorem (again, I'm ignoring open sets issues, because smoothness is a local property), hence $\Phi=\pi_{\Bbb{R}^m}\circ F^{-1}$ being the composition of a linear (hence $C^{\infty}$) map together with a $C^1$ map makes the entire composition $C^1$ (chain rule). Therefore, the map $\phi(x)=\Phi(0,x)$ is also $C^1$ (it's the composition of the (injective) linear, hence $C^{\infty}$ map $\iota_2(x):=(0,x)$ together with $\Phi$).